# Adding SecurityContextToken to SOAP 1.1 Message using Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, wss4j

I have to call a secure SOAP 1.1 (using X.509 Certificate) and currently getting error: **An error occurred when verifying security for the message.**

I suspect(and I stand corrected), the SOAP request generated has `BinarySecurityToken` instead of the expected `SecurityContextToken` in the SOAP header section. Unfortunately do not SOAP service logs to check the root cause of the security failure.

How would one configure the client so that the `SecurityContextToken` added removing the `BinarySecurityToken`?

**Server:** ASP.NET 4.0.30319

**Client:** Quarkus 2.3.1, Apache CXF 3.5.0, WSS4J 2.4.0, Java 17

**Client Configuration**

```java
        var factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setAddress("https://soap.service.bet/Service.svc");

        var props = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        props.put(ConfigurationConstants.ACTION, ConfigurationConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + ConfigurationConstants.SIGNATURE);
        props.put(ConfigurationConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, callbackHandler());
        props.put(ConfigurationConstants.USER, "alias");
        props.put(ConfigurationConstants.SIGNATURE_USER, "alias");
        props.put(ConfigurationConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, ""file-path);
        props.put(ConfigurationConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");

        var outInterceptor = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
        outInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
        factory.getOutInterceptors().add(outInterceptor);

        var inInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor();
        inInterceptor.setPrettyLogging(true);
        factory.getInInterceptors().add(inInterceptor);

        factory.setServiceClass(DocumentService.class);

        client = factory.create(DocumentService.class);
```

***SOAP Request Created*

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                       soap:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
                    EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                    ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                    wsu:Id="X509-4749bc58-cae6-43cf-8003-1bd2074646a2">base64-encoded-certificate</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-71963650-36aa-4aa1-b60a-40ad40785b5b">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-2847b44b-8392-4d1f-9624-30d982fe1a79">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>digest-value</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>signature-value</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-0fb9d706-78f4-4941-b993-1bb680cc74d1">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                            wsu:Id="STR-81744af4-f79f-428d-969e-f3d106c4c769">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-4749bc58-cae6-43cf-8003-1bd2074646a2"
                                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-f8046bd5-2eae-4321-83b1-1f9c54191751">
                <wsu:Created>2022-01-12T08:52:07.692Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-01-12T08:57:07.692Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://target-url.svc</wsa:To>
        <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://iermdocument.acmegroup.net/DocumentService/ProtectDocument</wsa:Action>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
               wsu:Id="id-2847b44b-8392-4d1f-9624-30d982fe1a79">
        <ns2:ProtectDocument xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Document.DTO"
                             xmlns:ns2="https://iermdocument.acmegroup.net/DocumentService"
                             xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <ns2:protectDocumentRequest>
                <DocumentContent>byte array of file contents</DocumentContent>
                <DocumentId>document-id</DocumentId>
                <FileName>filename.pdf</FileName>
                <TemplateId>reference-template</TemplateId>
            </ns2:protectDocumentRequest>
        </ns2:ProtectDocument>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Expected SOAP Message**

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">https://iermdocument.acmegroup.net/DocumentService/ProtectDocument</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7a83fb99-ad23-4854-b6f6-1ed40b4ac05d</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://target-url.svc</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2015-11-16T19:07:31.193Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2015-11-16T19:12:31.193Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <c:SecurityContextToken u:Id="uuid-c164b012-61e3-419b-9f59-85346cbcdaa3-1" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
                <c:Identifier>urn:uuid:b8e739ef-b550-4e46-a4b5-35bb1a95f094</c:Identifier>
            </c:SecurityContextToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>digest-value</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>signature-value</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" URI="#uuid-c164b012-61e3-419b-9f59-85346cbcdaa3-1"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <ProtectDocument xmlns="https://iermdocument.acmegroup.net/DocumentService">
            <protectDocumentRequest xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACME.Document.DTO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <b:DocumentContent>byte array of file contents</b:DocumentContent>
                <b:DocumentId>document-id</b:DocumentId>
                <b:FileName>filename.pdf</b:FileName>
                <b:TemplateId>reference-template</b:TemplateId>
            </protectDocumentRequest>
        </ProtectDocument>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```